# How to get src value from the class in the attr?

Tags: jquery

```
.attr('href', 'http://example.com/');
```

I want to get a link from the class a.myLink...

like here:

```
.attr('href', '');

<a href="http://example.com/" class="myLink"></a>
```

Here is my code

```
.$('<iframe src="" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>').attr('src', '.link here');
```

Comment: `<a>` tags don't have a `src`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to call the attr function on a valid object. Then leave the second parameter out as that will SET the href attribute. Calling without the second parameter will GET the href attribute from the object.

GETTER:

```
var href = $('.myLink').attr('href');
```

This will store the href in a variable

SETTER:

```
$('.myLink').attr('href','new href value');
```

This will set the html to:

```
<a href='new href value' class='myLink'></a>
```

In your case your selector is invalid. Try this instead:

```
$('iframe').attr('src');
```

Comment: "In your case your selector is invalid."  Why? It works.

Comment: @NothWild If it works then you wouldn't be here asking wouldn't you? Be a little more open-minded about people's suggestions. They help you in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You already made it all the way, you just had to select the element using the class name (which would have been `$('.myLink')`). Try this,

```
$('.myLink').attr('href');
```

As @MarcB has raised, hyperlinks have an `href`, and not `src` attribute — fix this too.

Comment: Sorry, it does not fit in my case.
Here is my code.`$('<iframe src="" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>').attr('src', '.link here');`

Comment: @NothWild Just try his solution. It should work. It will give you the `href` link.

Comment: @NothWild, why are you using that code in the element selector? That is not how you select the element based on its class name.

Comment: @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan, This code is only part of the specific function of a modal window.

Comment: @NothWild, I am unsure why that is being used to select a hyperlink using its class. That code doesn't do anything near what is expected. Can you show me where it is being used?